# Python 3 - Replacing words in a sentence with its index value

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, file

I am writing a program that takes a sentence input from the user as a string (str1Input) and then writes that sentence to a file. After splitting the sentence into a list (str1), the program identifies the unique words and writes it to the same file. I then need to replace each word in the sentence (str1Input) with it's index value. by reading from the file containing the sentence

For instance, if i had "i like to code in python and code things" this would be (str1Input) i would then use "str1Input.split()" which changes it to **{'i','like','to','code','in','python','and','code','things'}**. After finding the unique values i would get: **{'and', 'code', 'like', 'i', 'things', 'python', 'to', 'in'}.**

I have a problem as I am unsure as to how i would read from the file to replace each word in the sentence with the index value of that word. here is the code so far:

```
str1Input = input("Please enter a sentence: ")

str1 = str1Input.split()

str1Write = open('str1.txt','w')
str1Write.write(str1Input)
str1Write.close()

print("The words in that sentence are: ",str1)

unique_words = set(str1)

print("Here are the unique words in that sentence: " ,unique_words)
```

If anyone could help me with this that would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Would the output be like this `{3, 2,6, 1, 7, 5, 0, 1, 4}` ?